# django:postgres Querying Boolean Field with Null Values

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, django-models

I have a table with around 150 million rows. I have added a new Boolean field which was not there in the old rows. So, I added null in those rows and created the field.

```
ride_active = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I migrated it to DB and added an admin filter on this field.

```
list_filter = (
    'ride_active',
)
```

[image: Filter Values]

Now, all the previous rows have `Null` value, so `Unknown` filter value is working as fine. But while filtering for `Yes` and `No`, the query takes too much time and it results in `Bad Gateway`.

When I explain the query(on test environment),

```
Index Scan Backward using iot_data_nov_pkey on iot_data_nov  
(cost=0.44..1604685.17 rows=12708380 width=311)
  Filter: ride_active
```

I don't think adding an index on this field will be a good idea. How can I speed up my query on this field where the value is True/False, creating a partial index?

Comment: postgres has [multiple index types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html) each with a different algorithm. Have you checked them out?